# What kind of finish does this need to be weatherproof/durable?

Tags: finishing, joinery, wood, furniture

[image: Cane]

I'm not sure what type of wood this is, only that a Star Jasmine is responsible for killing the tree this branch came from.

If I can prepare this without you needing to know the wood type, what sorts of things do I need to coat it with for it to be completely weatherproof and possibly something to make it more durable? When this is completed, I was hoping it would last for a long time if not forever. Intended as a walking cane, it will be shortened, handle added and foot installed at the bottom. **I'm assuming it will be used daily as a cane to get around with**. So any suggestion on what to use is very helpful.

Comment: No way anyone will be able to identify the wood for you from this photo, much too little to go on. Apart from that wood IDs were decided on early as being off-topic for this SE.

Comment: Are IDs for the type of tools used for carving the top portion of this cane off limits on this SE too? I was about to make a thread asking that.

Comment: The secondary thing, the interchangeable tops, should be asked separately. As much as possible it should be one query per Question especially if they are unrelated as here.

Comment: No, tool-type recommendations are completely fine. Read [this](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/help), it's a bit long but it covers most things.

Comment: I forgot the follow-up, where can I go for a wood identification on this site?

Comment: No wood IDs anywhere on StackExchange as far as I know. Your best bet would be a conventional forum but I'm fairly sure there's too little to go on from this one picture to get an ID. If you had photos of the tree, ideally of the leaves (bark is often no help), that might be enough but even from whole boards it can be very difficult and sometimes impossible to get a firm ID aaand you may be dealing with a species that nobody harvests for wood so there's no familiarity among woodworkers. Anyway, does the species actually matter? If it seems springy enough and tough enough it probably is :-)

Comment: If you want a wood identification, you can go to the Center for Wood Anatomy Research (part of the USDA’s Forest Products Laboratory). According to The Wood Database, they provide a free service available to all US citizens, and will ID up to five samples per person per year. (This assumes you are a US citizen, of course, which is certainly not true of all members here!) https://www.fpl.fs.fed.us/research/centers/woodanatomy/wood_idfactsheet.php

Answer (score 1):

That's a really cool find and looks like it will make an excellent walking stick/cane!

Wood generally lasts a really long time, especially when not laying on the dirt and continually exposed to the elements. Does it need to be coated?

I would just finish (sand/scrape) the hand-hold area well enough to avoid splinters. It <s>might</s> will wear and darken from skin oil/dirty hands, but that could be considered "character" that's added over the years. Especially after the user has passed - it becomes a family heirloom *because* of the wear.

I can see putting a metal cap on the base to protect it from splintering/crushing from the repeated banging into the ground with each step, especially if used on pavement. A small metal cup hand hammered to fit might work. My FIL would probably drill a hole in the end and run a small lag bolt in and use that. (Kinda kills the heirloom quality workmanship, to be fair.)

Maybe a rubber tip would be a better bet so it's not so noisy on pavement. A screw-in rubber foot might work well. I'd look for something that has a fairly easily replaceable rubber piece that goes into a fixed fitting. Drill a hole, squeeze in some epoxy, screw in the fitting. Buy a stock of replacement rubber tips now (products do go out of production), and present the finished work.